# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num' for getter (as double) is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a personal expense tracker app in Flutter. I want to output a percentage of daily expenses compared to the total weekly expense. So, I need to GET the total sum of the week in `Double` datatype through `.fold()` method. But the inspector shows **"The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'."** I tired both `as double` and `as int`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_module3/models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import './chart_bar.dart';

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Transaction> recentTransaction; 
  

  Chart(this.recentTransactions);

  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTrandactionValues {
    return List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
        Duration(days: index),
      );
      var totalSum = 0.0;

      for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
        if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
          totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
        }
      }

      return {
        "Day": DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 1),
        'amount': totalSum,
      };


  double  get totalSpending {
    return groupedTrandactionValues.fold(0, (prev, element) {
     
      return prev + element['amount'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(groupedTrandactionValues);
    return Card(
      child: Row(),
    );
  }
}
```

`groupTransactionValues` returned:

```
  [{"Day": "W", "amount": 86.52},
           {"Day": "T", "amount": 45.0},
           {"Day":" M"," amount": 23.0}, 
           {"Day": "S", "amount": 45.0},
           {"Day": "S", "amount": 67.0}, 
           {"Day": "F", "amount": 98.0}, 
           {'Day': "T", "amount": 45.0}];
            });
          }
```

I tried `as double`

```
double  get totalSpending {
    return groupedTrandactionValues.fold(0.0, (prev, element) {
     
      return prev + element['amount'] as double;
    });
  }
```

Also `as int`:

```
int  get totalSpending {
    return groupedTrandactionValues.fold(0, (prev, element) {
    
      return prev + element['amount'] as int;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
`List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTrandactionValues`
to
`List<Map<String, dynamic>> get groupedTrandactionValues`

Comment:  It's fixed. Thank you so much for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

When getting an element from a map `element['amount']` it can be null, so do this.

```dart
return prev + (element['amount'] ?? 0.0);
```

This means if the amount in element is null for some reason it'll add `0.0`

Edit:
This works for me in dartpad

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> data = [
    {"Day": "W", "amount": 86.52},
    {"Day": "T", "amount": 45.0},
    {"Day": "M", "amount": 23.0},
    {"Day": "S", "amount": 45.0},
    {"Day": "S", "amount": 67.0},
    {"Day": "F", "amount": 98.0},
    {'Day': "T", "amount": 45.0},
  ];

  double totalSpending() {
    return data.fold(0.0, (double prev, Map<String, Object> element) {
      return prev + (element['amount'] as double? ?? 0.0);
    });
  }

  var total = totalSpending();
  print(total);
```

`409.52`

`(element['amount'] as double? ?? 0.0)` means get the amount as a double or null, if it is null use `0.0`

Comment: It's helpful. But the issue persists after this. 

Comment: @Mafruh I've tested it and my edit should work for you now

Comment: Yeh! It's working in my dartpad too.  Thanks a lot, bro!